# How to add a prefix/suffix to text per line using javascript?

Tags: javascript

how would i add a prefix per line to a text area.. example:

this is the content of the textarea:
`hello
124`

and i would want to add a [b] prefix and suffix to each line so that when i click a button the result will be:

`[b]hello[/b]

[b]124[/b]`

please help me :(

Comment: Ironically, the answer box is the answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function TextDefine(val){
var i= 0;                

var array1 = val.value.split("\n");
for ( i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array1[i] = "[b]" + array1[i] + "[/b]";
}
val.value = array1.join("\n");

}
</script>

<textarea name="data" id="data"></textarea>
<input type="button" name="submit1" value="Submit" onclick="TextDefine(document.getElementById('data'))" />
```

Comment: thanks this worked but how would i make the result display in another box?

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        function TextDefine(val){
    var i= 0;                
var array1 = val.value.split("\n");
for ( i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    array1[i] = "[b]" + array1[i] + "[/b]";
}
document.getElementById('another').value = array1.join("\n");
                        }
                        </script>
<textarea name="data" id="data"></textarea>
<textarea name="another" id="another"></textarea>
<input type="button" name="submit1" value="Submit" onclick="TextDefine(document.getElementById('data'))" />

Comment: if you like the answer then you should accept it by checking on right arrow sign.

Comment: how do i implement this to the text area beside "another:" here: http://pastehtml.com/view/1cavex5.html

Answer (score 4):

```
text = document.getElementById("the_textarea").value;
document.getElementById("the_textarea").value = text.replace(/.+/g, "[b]$&[/b]");
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: There's no need to create a capturing group: `.replace(/.+/g, "[b]$&[/b]")`.

Answer (score 3):

Using only plain Javascript, you can do:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("yourTextAreaID");
var lines = textArea.value.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
    lines[i] = "[b]" + lines[i] + "[/b]";
}
textArea.value = lines.join("\n");
```

Or, as @Alin Purcaru suggested, without using a loop:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("yourTextAreaID");
textArea.value = "[b]" + textArea.value.split("\n").join("[/b]\n[b]") + "[/b]";
```

Comment: do textareas only use `\n` regardless of OS? not `\r\n`?

Comment: @Ralph, in my experience, using the `\n` delimiter in client-side code works in all browsers. Newline characters are translated to ` \r\n` when posted to the server, though.

Comment: Using `textArea.value = '[b]'+lines.join("[/b]\n[b]")+'[/b]';` would work better and avoid the need for a loop. Edit: as box9 used in his answer.

Comment: I put ur second answer in a <javascript> tag but it doesn't work :( how do i make this work?

Answer (score 3):

using joins and splits:

```
var prefix = '[b]', suffix = '[/b]',
   txt = document.getElementById('myText');
txt.value = prefix + txt.value.split('\n').join(suffix + '\n' + prefix) + suffix;
```

Comment: i tried to put ur answer in a <javascript> tag but it doesn't work, sorry i'm a noob

Answer (score -1):

1. Convert the string into an array starting at position 1 of the array.
2. Push the prefix at position 0 of the array.
3. Convert the array back to a string with join.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).